# How to send POST (json file with urls) request via chrome extension to deployed FLASK APP?

Tags: javascript, post, google-chrome-extension, request

my Flask app should read urls from news site (urls of articles), and analyze properties of articles (readibility indexes, html properties etc.).

I have no problem with running it locally. I'm using to save urls this Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabstore-plugin/jngplpdonggccbjlmbphlbancacmpmpp?hl=en). After clicking on button Save it -it saves all urls of open tabs to json and and after that I run my flask LOCALLY, and it reads these urls from json saved in my PC (and after that I analyze text properties...).

But, in few weeks I would like to deploy my flask (on Heroku/PythonEverywhere/ i just haven't decided where ...) and I realize, it won't work like this, and I need to figure out   ***how can I send POST request (json file with urls) to Flask app running on server (not locally).***

I edited little bit TABS store chrome plugin - I add button to run my flask app (just to open new site == my flask app) and whole process should looks like that I click to Save url and after that I click on button which open new tab with my Flask app (which already get urls from chrome plugin).

EDITED...

I just find out how to show via Flask the ouput (I simulated POST via POSTMAN app) ... there is chunk of my flask app, where I show posted URL.

```py
@app.route('/jsonexample', methods=['POST'])
def jsonexample():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    #json is formatted as list, so we choose 1st element from list
    url_n1 = req_data[0]             

    return '''
           The 1st url is: {}
           '''.format(url_n1)
```

**But can somebody help me with POST request in JavaScript??? I am quite newbie in js.**

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "tabStore_MREVAK_version",
  "description": "This extension will store the urls of all the tabs opened and launch the FLASK  APP",
  "version": "1.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "fontSettings"
   ]
}
```

Here is my popup.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>tabStore</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <input type="button" id="btnOpenNewTab" value="Click to open new tab"/> -->
    <button id="saveActionId"> Save urls </button>
    <button id="btnOpenNewTab"> Click to open App </button>
    <button id="loadActionId"> Load </button>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" style="visibility: hidden;" multiple /> 
    <a id="downloadAnchorElem" style="display:none"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

And there is my whole logic of plugin - popup.js:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    //
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }

    // button to open stackoverflow-just placeholder, it will be link on my flask app
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // your button here
        var link = document.getElementById('btnOpenNewTab');
        // onClick's logic below:
            link.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var newURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
                chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
            });
    });




    var saveActionButton = document.getElementById('saveActionId');
    saveActionButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myArray = [];
        chrome.tabs.query({"currentWindow": true},  //{"windowId": targetWindow.id, "index": tabPosition});
        function (array_of_Tabs) {  //Tab tab
            arrayLength = array_of_Tabs.length;
            //alert(arrayLength);
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                myArray.push(array_of_Tabs[i].url);
            }
            obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray));
            //alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
            var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
            var dlAnchorElem = document.getElementById('downloadAnchorElem');
            dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href",     dataStr     );
            dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", "tabs.json");
            dlAnchorElem.click();
        });
    }, false);


    var loadActionButton = document.getElementById('loadActionId');
    loadActionButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('files').click();
    }, false);


    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var start = 0;
            var stop = f.size - 1;
            reader = new FileReader();
            //alert(f.name);
            // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
                    jsonObj = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);
                    for (var i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++) {
                         chrome.tabs.create({"url": jsonObj[i]}); //chrome.tabs.create({"url": 'http://www.google.com'});
                    }
                }
            };
            var blob = f.slice(start, stop + 1);
            reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

}, false);
```

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: Hey, i just edited my question, I think I am in half way, but I am struggling with JS, any ideas?